# Angular JS - Form validation with dynamic value in a message

Tags: angularjs

I have a html with an input field.

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="medium-8 columns" ng-class="{'error': form.name.$invalid && form.name.$touched}">

                            <input  floating-label

                                    name="name"
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Your name"
                                    ng-model="name"
                                    ng-minlength="5"
                                    ng-maxlength="25"
                                    validateName
                                    required>
                            <ng-messages for="form.name.$error" ng-if="form.name.$touched" class="cs-input__messages" role="alert">
                                <div ng-messages-include="partial/error-messages.html"></div>
                            </ng-messages>
                        </div>
```

error-messages.html looks like the below one.

```
<ng-message when="invalidName" class="message errorNopath" translate>Name is not valid</ng-message>
```

validateName directive is as follows,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.validateName', [])
        .directive('validateName', validateName);

    /* @ngInject */
    function validateName($stateParams) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',

            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

                function customValidator(ngModelValue) {


                        if(some condition)
                            ctrl.$setValidity('invalidName', false);

                        } else {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('invalidName', true);
                        }
                    }

                    return ngModelValue;
                }
                ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Here, when the validation fails, i see the error message, "Name is not valid" as defined in the error-message.html.

But, I am looking for a message with some dynamic text in it.

For example, Name -  is not valid. Here  should be a link. This Some_Name is from database and it can be different value for different input.